# The $index in foreach binding seems not work

Tags: knockout.js

I want to use the `$index` context property in a `foreach` binding.  But it does not work for me.

I have a table which shows all persons.  What I want to do is when there is more than 1 person in the list, I want to show a delete button.  But the button never shows on my view.  What is the problem?

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach:Persons">
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text:Name()"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text:Id()"></span></td>
                <td>
                    <!--ko if:($index > 0)-->
                    <button data-bind="click:Delete($data)}">DEL</button>
                    <!--/ko-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$index` is an observable (a function).  You have to invoke it to retrieve the value.

Comment: @JeffMercado is correct...Try the following syntax: 
`<!--ko if:($index() > 0)-->`

Comment: WOW.分かりました.Thank you so much. It works.